# Is there anyway to prevent chrome from displaying suggestions in dropdown list in chrome using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I got a trouble when I use input tag type password.
I stored my password before and every time I focus on password field browser recommend old username and password like under picture.

[image]

is any way to prevent it using javascript?
I know how to turn off it by go to setting of browser but I want to turn off it using javascript because I am not sure if the client has turned that off with setting.

Comment: Try with autocomplete="off" prop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: I tried but autocomplete="off" doesn't work in  new version chrome. Can u click my photo when i focus on password field browser suggest my both username and password :((

Comment: So try `autocomplete="fsdkfj"` (Or any other random attribute value - It works for me)

Comment: Almost autocomplete just work in type text but my field password still suggest to me even though I tried set type attribute from password to text, it's still suggest :((

Comment: don't, modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion